# maven repository not returning html text properly using python

Tags: python, html, maven, beautifulsoup, get

I am trying to access the maven repository url, fetch the html data and print the title but it is showing wrong data. I am using python Beautiful Soup library. I believe something is wrong while fetching up the  html data. Can someone help here
CODE:

```
   from html.parser 
   import HTMLParser
   from turtle import title
   import requests
   from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
   url= "https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven/maven-plugin-api/3.8.3"
   r=requests.get(url)
   htmlcontent=r.content
   soup =BeautifulSoup(htmlcontent,'html.parser')
   print(soup.title)
```

It is returning "Please Wait... | Cloudflare" which is wrong info.

Comment: Why are you trying to read the HTML part? Furthermore central (https://search.maven.org/) has a REST API and an API guide https://central.sonatype.org/search/rest-api-guide/

Answer (score 0):

Maven Repository is protected against robot requests and DDoS attacks with [Cloudflare](https://cloudflare.com/)'s (reverse proxy) CDN. That means that you first connect to cloudflare server, then, if you were allowed to continue, you will be redirected to original server. That's why you are getting `Please Wait...` as it's default DDoS protection waiting page.